# How to get SelBlocks Selenium IDE extension to find XML file?

Tags: selenium-ide

Hopefully, Chris Noe, is in the house...

Selblocks is an extension for Selenium IDE that provides control-flow constructs such as if/then/else, looping and subroutines.

I'm trying to give interation over an XML file a whirl and am running into an error. It seems it can't find the XML file. The XML file is co-located with my Sel scripts. Please see the screenshot attached.

Is there a source for more documentation or examples? Like the sample test suite you have a picture of on the extension page?

Thanks,
Cameron

http://cl.ly/AzzT

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and the problem turned out to be that my XML was invalid. In my case it was because one of the parameters I was using was a url containing ampersands. Changing `&` to `&amp;` fixed the problem for me, and the variables loaded perfectly.